# Features of SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, features

We can see a list of features in **Site** > **Site Settings** > **Site Actions** > **Manage Site Features**. Is there any site where I can find a description for each and every features that is/ could be mentioned in my `Site Features`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the following SharePoint Powershell code to show all features with its description , scope , title, id.

- Open Sharepoint management Shell as administrator.
- Run the following Code.

> ```
> $lcid=1033
> $delimiter = "*"
> Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | % { Get-SPFeature -Identity $_ | % { $_.DisplayName + $delimiter + $_.GetTitle($lcid) +$delimiter +$_.Scope
> + $delimiter + $_.Id + $delimiter + $_.GetDescription($lcid)} } >"C:\Features.csv"
> ```

- It will export all features to CSV file.

Credit to [Listing All SharePoint Server 2013 Features – Including Name, Title, Scope, ID and Description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/razi/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-server-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description/) he also list all features with its description if you can't use SharePoint PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of available site features for SP Server 2013:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activate-features-for-sites-787f3ba1-9df6-480a-ab4c-9f4525490cb9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: I have checked that link already. It has got few features missing from the one that's visible in my feature gallery, like what about AppFeatures ? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these lists of features (site and site collection):
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/razi/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-server-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description/

http://www.spsdemo.com/lists/features/all%20sharepoint%20features.aspx

From what I see they contain even the features not visible in the user interface (hidden features) like side loading that may need to be enabled at some point. The lists contain feature GUIDs and brief descriptions.